# How to pass an operator()() of a functor allocated on the heap, to a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

For the functor:

```
class F
{
bool proceed;
public:
F():proceed(true) {}
void operator()() 
{
 while(proceed) {std::cout<<".";}
 std::cout<<"stopped\n";
}
void stopIt() {proceed=false;}
};
```

I'm able to create an object and pass it to a [TBB thread](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/appendices/compatibility_features/tbb_thread_cls.htm) (it's now under the std namespace):

```
F foo;
std::thread t(foo);
```

This works fine, except that when I call `foo.stopIt()`, the while loop does not stop. So I assume the `foo` I'm passing to the thread actually creates a new object.

To prevent that, I tried:

```
F* foo = new F();
```

But `std::thread t(foo);` doesn't work. `t(*foo)` doesn't work. `t(&foo)` doesn't work. `t(foo->())` doesn't. Tried a few other techniques too. No luck.

So how can I pass the `operator()()` function to the thread and be able to call `stopIt()` later?

UPDATE:

In response to Nathan's answer, this is what I tried:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36d70da08c1210f1

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
//#include <random>
#include <functional>
#include <tbb/compat/thread>

template< class T >
T* addressof(T& arg)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(
               &const_cast<char&>(
                  reinterpret_cast<const volatile char&>(arg)));
}

template <class T>
class reference_wrapper {
public:
  // types
  typedef T type;

  // construct/copy/destroy
  reference_wrapper(T& ref) : _ptr(addressof(ref)) {}
  //reference_wrapper(T&&) = delete;
  //reference_wrapper(const reference_wrapper&) noexcept = default;

  // assignment
  //reference_wrapper& operator=(const reference_wrapper& x) noexcept = default;

  // access
  operator T& () const { return *_ptr; }
  T& get() const { return *_ptr; }

private:
  T* _ptr;
};

class F
{
    bool proceed;
public:
    F():proceed(true) {}
    void operator()()
    {
        while(proceed) {std::cout<<".";}
        std::cout<<"stopped\n";
    }
    void stopIt() {proceed=false;}
};


class ref {
public:
  typedef F type;
  ref(F& ref) : _ptr(addressof(ref)) {}
  operator F& () const { return *_ptr; }
  F& get() const { return *_ptr; }
private:
  F* _ptr;
};



int main()
{
    //using namespace std::literals;
    F foo;
    std::thread t(ref(foo));
    std::cout<<"running";
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);
    foo.stopIt();
    //t.join();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`thread` takes it parameters by value.  If you need the  thread to get the same object that you have in the calling function then you need to wrap it with [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref)

In this case to run the code and get some output we can run:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals;
    F foo;
    std::thread t(std::ref(foo));
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);
    foo.stopIt();
    t.join();
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54443f1b403f8700)</kbd>

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't work. Not because of `std::ref`, but because the compiler couldn't recognize `std::ref`. Even after I gave it the proper include path to `#include<functional>`. For now I've tried `F* foo = new F(); F& bar = foo; 
std::thread t(bar);`, but even this creates a separate object inside the thread. The `stopIt()` function does not work on it. Is there any other solution?

Comment: @Nav what compiler and settings are you using?  Also see my answer with its example.

Comment: There's no support for c++14, so tried c++11. No luck `g++    -c -g -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o main.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"`. Had tried your example from corilu. I have `gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) (GCC) ` (actually on Centos 6.5, 64 bit). `std::ref` is too new I guess. Perhaps a different, older technique would help?

Comment: @Nav Have you tried compiling with `-std=c++0x`?  Also can you upgrade your compiler?  If not you can make your own [`std::ref()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) and [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper).

Comment: Tried creating my own reference wrapper with the code on the std::reference_wrapper page. I had to comment out the C++11 specific code, but it still didn't work. If I could just understand what exactly is it that forces the thread to use the same reference instead of creating a new object, I could do this on my own. I assumed it would be the `std::addressof` which does it with `reinterpret_cast`. Perhaps what I'd like more than a direct solution, is an understanding of how std::ref accomplishes the task.

Comment: @Nav Can you post the code that you tried that didn't work?  I would like to take a look at it.  If you don't want to edit it into the answer you could share a link to it using coliru or ideone.  A reference wrapper is nothing special.  it store a pointer to an object and has an implicit conversion function that makes it act like a normal reference.

Comment: Here it is: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36d70da08c1210f1. Also updated it in my question.